# Downloading and re-uploading all product images in shopify

Tags: php, image, upload, shopify

I have over 1000 products on my website with images. Each image is 600kb+, I would like to download all of them, optimize the image and re-upload them in a smaller size.'

Is there a shortcut to downloading all the images, and replace them all at once I upload them with the same name? Or do I have to do it one by one again?

Comment: you can automate using shopify api: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product

Comment: Thanks for the response. i 'll check but i have to update the previously uploaded images in products.